# org mode - inline image float to right overrided by codeblock

Tags: org-mode

When export to html,the inline image has been overrided by inline image:

```
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil
#+TITLE:
#+STARTUP: showeverything 
#+STARTUP: indent
#+OPTIONS: html-postamble:nil
#+HTML_HEAD: <style>pre.src {background-color: #eff0f1;width 50%;}</style>
#+ATTR_HTML: :style border:12px solid black;float:right;

* Unit circle
#+ATTR_HTML: <style>pre {width 50%;}</style>
#+BEGIN_SRC gnuplot :exports both :file unitcircle.png 
reset
set border lw 1.5
set style line 1 lc rgb '#0060ad' lt 1 lw 2     # --- blue
set style line 2 lc rgb '#dd181f' lt 1 lw 2     # --- red

unset key; unset tics; unset border
set size ratio -1
set xrange [-1.2:1.2]
set yrange [-1.2:1.2]
set trange [0:2*pi]

set parametric

r = 1.0
h = r / sqrt(2.)
set arrow from 0,0 to h,h nohead ls 2
set label 'r' at 0.28,0.45 textcolor ls 2

fx(t) = r*cos(t)
fy(t) = r*sin(t)

plot fx(t),fy(t) ls 1
#+END_SRC
#+CAPTION: Fig. 1 Unitcircle
#+ATTR_HTML: :style border:2px solid red;float:right; :width:50%
#+RESULTS:
[[file:unitcircle.png]]

* Cosine
#+BEGIN_SRC gnuplot :exports both :file cosine.png
reset 
set xrange [-1*pi:1*pi]
set yrange [-1.5:1.5]
f(x) = cos(x)
g(x) = 0
plot f(x) title 'cos(x)' with lines linestyle 1, \
     g(x) notitle with lines linestyle 2
#+END_SRC
#+CAPTION: Fig. 2 cosine
#+ATTR_HTML: :style border:2px solid red;float:right; :width:50%
#+RESULTS:
[[file:cosine.png]]
```

Output:

[image]

But I wish:

- The codeblock should not override the inline image.
- The Caption lines should float with the image (above the image exactly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS to customize div.org-src-container element.

```
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil
#+TITLE:
#+STARTUP: showeverything 
#+STARTUP: indent
#+OPTIONS: html-postamble:nil
#+HTML_HEAD: <style type="text/css">div.org-src-container{border:1px solid green;width:50%;float:left;}</style>
#+HTML_HEAD: <style>pre.src {background-color: #eff0f1;margin:0 0 0 0;}</style>
#+HTML_HEAD: <style type="text/css">div.figure{border:1px solid green;overflow:auto;}</style>
# #+ATTR_HTML: :style border:12px solid black;float:right;
# #+ATTR_HTML: :style border:2px solid red;float:right; :width:50%
* Unit circle
#+BEGIN_SRC gnuplot :exports both :file unitcircle.png 
reset
set border lw 1.5
set style line 1 lc rgb '#0060ad' lt 1 lw 2
set style line 2 lc rgb '#dd181f' lt 1 lw 2

unset key; unset tics; unset border
set size ratio -1
set xrange [-1.2:1.2]
set yrange [-1.2:1.2]
set trange [0:2*pi]

set parametric

r = 1.0
h = r / sqrt(2.)
set arrow from 0,0 to h,h nohead ls 2
set label 'r' at 0.28,0.45 textcolor ls 2

fx(t) = r*cos(t)
fy(t) = r*sin(t)

plot fx(t),fy(t) ls 1
#+END_SRC
#+CAPTION: Unitcircle
#+RESULTS:
[[file:unitcircle.png]]

* Cosine
#+BEGIN_SRC gnuplot :exports both :file cosine.png
reset
unset key; unset tics; unset border 
set xrange [-1*pi:1*pi]
set yrange [-1.5:1.5]
f(x) = cos(x)
g(x) = 0
plot f(x) title 'cos(x)' with lines linestyle 1, \
     g(x) notitle with lines linestyle 2
#+END_SRC
#+CAPTION: cosine
#+RESULTS:
[[file:cosine.png]]
```

Output:

[image]